# Can you transfer from Ukraine International airlines to British Airways at Kiev-Boryspil without clearing immigration (only hand luggage)?

Tags: transit, airports, british-airways, ukraine, kyiv

So I'm considering flying Tbilisi-Kiev-London (TBS-KBP-LHR), with the TBS-KBP leg flown by Ukraine International Airlines (UIA), and the KBP-LHR leg by British Airways (BA)

I will not be able to have my passport with me, only my ID Card, which is accepted for entry/Exit in both Georgia and the UK.

Regarding transiting Ukraine, the IATA database says it's allowed with my ID "at Kiev-Boryspil on Ukraine International Airlines".

I understand why it's restricted to KBP (because that's Ukraine's only airport with airside transit), but what about it having to be on UIA?

If I had checked-in luggage, it would make perfect sense, but since I'm going Hand luggage only, my question becomes:

**Is it possible to Transfer from UIA to BA at KBP without clearing Immigration?** Since TBS has no BA desk (and I won't have Access to a Printer), can one collect the BA Boarding pass in the transit area at KBP?

I Need to know this in order to know whether I can do this route.

Comment: Are these on separate tickets?

Comment: It would be, yes. Otherwise this wouldn't be an issue. But like I wrote, Hand luggage only

Comment: [KBP map and description](https://kbp.aero/en/passengers/transfer/) suggests it is possible (also my understanding is that currently all international flights are handled in terminal D there), however I would suggest to remove doubts by checking with the airport. Stumbling on Ukrainian immigration check without a passport is specifically a scenario I would hate to get it.

Comment: @RomanR. I know you can Transit without Clearing Immigration; the question is if it's possible to collect a BA Boarding pass at the Transfer desk. I've had some People tell me it only deals with UIA tickets, but I'm not sure if this is true

Comment: "If you don’t have boarding pass for your connecting flight you should proceed to the Transfer counter at the second level of terminal D" - I suppose it's what you will need.

Comment: There is a transit desk airside at Boryspil from which I've seen people collecting boarding passes.  I expect (but don't know for certain) that you can collect a BA boarding pass there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flights on UIA (PS) from TBS land at terminal D. Flights on BA to LHR depart from terminal D. PS and BA do have an interlining agreement*, so it should be possible to buy this as a single ticket.

As stated by Roman R, the airport provides [transfer](https://kbp.aero/en/passengers/transfer/) information which shows only a security control for transferring passengers and a transfer desk to collect onward boarding passes.

[image: KBP transfer]
<sub>(source: [kbp.aero](https://kbp.aero/f/1/passengers/transfer/INT-INT_UIA1.png))</sub>

BA also provide a [mobile app](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/checking-in/mobile-boarding-pass) and in most cases it is possible to use a mobile boarding pass. Alternatively it may be possible to check in online and print the BA boarding pass in advance.

*Although expertflyer says BA and PS have an e-ticket interlining agreement with each other, I can't actually bring up any ticket other than YY coded ones.

(ps. this is/was the only BA tagged question with no answer!)